# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com.aspose'

Tags: python, ubuntu, databricks, aspose-cells

I installed `aspose-cells` on databricks. When we run the code we get: `ModuleNotFoundError on apsosecells.api`

import the required libraries:

```py
import jpype
jpype.startJVM()
import asposecells
from asposecells.api import Workbook, FileFormatType, PdfSaveOptions
```

Traceback of error is following:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com.aspose'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3119747521735179> in <module>
----> 1 from asposecells.api import Workbook, FileFormatType, PdfSaveOptions

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asposecells/api.py in <module>
      8 from jpype import imports
      9 
---> 10 from com.aspose.cells.wrapper import StreamBuffer
     11 @JImplementationFor("com.aspose.cells.wrapper.StreamBuffer")
     12 class _StreamBuffer(object):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com.aspose'
```

Answer (score 1):

We evaluated your issue in details. We found there are some differences between using notebook and terminal environments. Aspose.Cells for Python via Java works absolutely fine on terminal env., but we got similar error in the notebook. Please try terminal environment as we might not fix such an issue for notebook using Databricks.

FYI, We used the following steps to test Aspose.Cells for Python via Java on underlying platforms and it works fine.

1). Create a Databricks node, Databricks Runtime Version: 8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12)

2). Select “Libraries” tab, click “Install New” button. In “Install Library” dialog, select “PyPI” tab, input “aspose-cells” and click “Install” button to install Aspose.Cells for Python via Java 21.9.0.

3). Select “Apps” tab, click “Launch Web Terminal” button to open a web terminal.

4). Check versions:
Ubuntu: VERSION=“18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)”
Python: 3.8.8
Java: openjdk version “1.8.0_282”
aspose-cells: 21.9.0
JPype1: 1.3.0

5). Test JPype1, it works fine.

```
import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *

jpype.startJVM()
from java.util import ArrayList

myList = ArrayList()
myList.add(1)
myList.add(2)

print('length:', len(myList))

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

6). Test aspose-cells, it works fine too.

```
import jpype
import asposecells
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook, FileFormatType

workbook = Workbook(FileFormatType.XLSX)
workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells().get("A1").putValue("Hello World")
workbook.save("output.xlsx")

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

7). We also tested on Databricks 7.3 LTS (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.0.1), it works fine too.

You may also post your queries in Aspose.Cells [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9), we can help you there.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.